# How to wait state change to render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So, I need to get the response from a request and then send it to another component. The problem is that my request isn't finished when the component call happens. So what I end up getting on the "TableComponent" is an empty array

This is the component I'm making the request at:

```
class Carrinho extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.getMateriais()
    }
    
    async getMateriais() {
        let service = new MateriaisService();
        service.getMateriais().then(res => res.json()).then((result) => {
            this.setState({materiais: result})
      
        })       
    }

render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <TableComponent materiais={this.state.materiais} itens={this.state.array_teste}></TableComponent>
        </div>
        );
    }
```

And this is how I'm setting my state on TableComponent.js :

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            materiais : props.materiais,
            }
```

Comment: You don't have to store the prop in child's state. You can use it directly in the child component

Comment: **await** service.getMateriais().then(res => res.json()).then((result) => {
            this.setState({materiais: result})
      
        })       

please add **await** as I have already declared in above

Comment: @JayParmar did that and still get and empty array on TableComponent

Comment: **res.json()**  what is the output?

Comment: @TheAlpha93 i'm sorry. I don't understand it

Comment: @JayParmar if I do this :this.setState({materiais: result}, console.log(result)) . I get what I need

Comment: I think the problem is that you did the second time **then** why you have to do that ? you can simply set the state after the first **then** no need to required second then.

Comment: @JayParmar to be honest with you, I'm working as an intern and I have only been working with react for 1 week, this is how the other requests on the project are made, the only difference is that they don't need to send it to another Component, but I do

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, because `this.getMateriais()` call in the constructor, won't trigger a new render. You'll need to use `componentDidMount` life cycle and `async/await` syntax.

```
class Carrinho extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.getMateriais()
    }
  
    async componentDidMount(){
        await this.getMateriais();
    }

    
    async getMateriais() {
        let service = new MateriaisService();
        const result = await service.getMateriais();
        const data = await result.json();
        this.setState({ materiais: result });       
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <TableComponent materiais={this.state.materiais} itens={this.state.array_teste}></TableComponent>
        </div>
        );
    }
```

However, `async/await` is not recommendable to deal with promises in React programming model. Instead, you should render a different component or a loading, while waiting.

```
class Carrinho extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getMateriais();
    }
    
    getMateriais() {
        let service = new MateriaisService();
        service.getMateriais().then(res => res.json()).then((result) => {
            this.setState({materiais: result})  
        })       
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            {this.state.materiais && <TableComponent materiais={this.state.materiais} itens={this.state.array_teste}></TableComponent>}
        </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: just read through your answer and it makes total sense, but for me reason I'm still getting an empty array on my component, maybe it's the way I'm declaring my state on TableComponent?

Comment: @placementw if you could edit your answer and show us the TableComponent, that'd be great

Comment: I have it at the end of the question, i'm declaring it on my constructor, and I have console.log to check state on componentDidMount

Comment: @placementw I meant the whole component, it's just the constructor

Comment: @Federuci Alecci that's what the component is for now, the constructor and componentDidMount, I'm just trying to get the response there